# Why are Proto-Germanic *fraiwą and Old Norse frjó / fræ cognate?

Tags: old-norse

Why are Proto-Germanic *fraiwą and Old Norse frjó / fræ (oblique stems frjóvi / frævi) cognate?
I don't understand why are PGmc *ai* and Old Norse *jó* / *æ* cognate?

[image]

The part of the table "History of Old Norse and Old Icelandic vowels" from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The development of Proto-Germanic ai in the North Germanic languages is very complex. It depends on a number of factors (stressed/unstressed, followed by w, r/R, h etc.) - see e.g. [Sandøy 2017](https://www.degruyter.com/view/book/9783110197068/10.1515/9783110197068-084.xml)

> **PGmc. ai > Proto-Norse æi** ([Fulk 2018:](https://www.jbe-platform.com/content/books/9789027263131) 70), which further developed into:

- ǣ (before w) ([Heusler 1921: 28](https://archive.org/details/altislndischesel00heus/page/28/mode/2up));
- ā (before r, h) (this ā further developed into ē in the i-umlaut environment);
- ei (in OWN) or  ē (OEN) ([Versloot 2017:](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/flih-2017-0010/html) 285);

In your post, you ask about frǽ (and its variant frjó; [Zoega 1926](https://onp.ku.dk/onp/onp.php?o24213#) says that fræ was "sometimes in old MSS. spelt freo or frjó (q.v.), but less rightly").

As you can easily notice, we have *w* after the diphthong in PGmc, which means PGmc ai developed into æ in Old Norse (see above), cf. Fulk 2018: 70

"In  addition,  Proto-Norse  æi developed to ON æ (i.e., /æː/) before w (which might be lost, §6.14), as in *aiwīn- > OIcel. ævi ‘age’ (cf. Go. aíws < *aiwaz) and hræ ‘corpse’ (cf. Go. hraíw)."

*Note:* the acute and the macron are used interchangeably here, to indicate length.

Comment: Is there a difference between the acute and the macron? I'm used to acutes indicating length in transcribed Old Norse, but it seems like there's a distinction here.

Comment: @Draconis hmm, I meant for the acute to show length, nothing else. Trying to fix it now :)